# Problem using Scirra Construct with Wine

Tags: 10.10, wine

Please see [the video](http://img210.imageshack.us/i/k9r.mp4/). When I try to use Construct's sprite editor, Why does the black screen appear?
I can not choose another color, only black.

How to fix this problem with Wine?

Answer (score 2):

Some steps to try based on the [AppDB page](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=18446) for this program:

1. Update to latest beta Wine ([instructions here](http://www.winehq.org/site/download-deb))
2. Run winetricks and tick a few of the boxes that are suggested on the AppDB howto page.  I suggest doing them one at a time.  To run winetricks, install the beta package as above and then type `winetricks` into a terminal.